# Installation of Ubuntu 12.10 on a tablet pc

Tags: tablet

I have a intel x86 based tablet with the following configuratioin: Processor-Atom N2600 1.6GHz, Memory 2GB, SSD 32GB and is touch enabled.
I install Ubuntu 12.10 and it detects everything from wireless to camera to bluetooth from the word go.  Touch works from the word go.  Then it ejects the cd from the external cdrom drive and tells you to remove media and press enter to reboot.  It hangs here.  I restart myself. The following are some of the messages that are on the black and white screen when its booting:

```
modem-manager[781]: <info> successfully loaded 20 plugins
starting mDNS/DNS-SD daemon [ok]
starting configure virtual network devices [ok]
skipping profile in /etc/appamor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
skipping profile in /etc/appamor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd [ok]
*stopping system V initialization compability [ok]
*starting automatic crash report generation [ok]
.
.
.
```

and stops at the following

```
*stopping save kernel messages [ok]
```

What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I Kindly Suggest you to go to the ubuntu recovery mode console and do the following things

```
sudo fsck
sudo apt-get clean
```